# C# WPF RDP ax control from MSTSCLib for Hyper-V problems

Tags: c#, wpf, activex, rdp, mstsc

Currently occupied making a little RDP client in **WPF C#** for VM's hosted by Hyper-V. This client should have no management at all so solely connect to it, and be able to use the machine. So no options of stopping/starting/etc the VM.

Control using: AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting initialized at runtime and being placed in a WindowsFormsHost

### The problems are:

1) I lied, there is one feature which should be possible: Sending Ctrl + Alt + Del. I have made a button for this on the client of course. I have tried several possibilities but I failed in each one of them, I even can't send a single 'A' to the VM.

**Possibilities I tried:**

a) Keyboard simulation through the SendInput native call from user32.dll

- When i did the SendKeystroke 'control, alt and something else' and then went to the VM and for example pressed F, the control + F command was triggered. Or i could start selecting multiple files (like shift).
- other than that, i tried setting some properties on and off on the control's advanced settings/securedsettings

So unless I am doing something wrong that the keys are not being triggered, This method fails for me

---

b) Using InputManager

```
PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
KeyEventArgs insertStuff = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, source, 0, Key.D0);
insertStuff.RoutedEvent = UIElement.KeyDownEvent;
InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(insertStuff);
```

this is the usercontrol where the windowsformhost is situated, I tried replacing this by this.winformshost, but no luck there either

---

c) tried another way but failed and forgot, wasn't very pretty anyway.

---

2) The second problem is focus, to be more precise: focus when the application is launched within a VM.

I'll explain in detail:
At developer machine nothing is wrong. But when I launch the application from within an RDP to a Virtual machine (**A**) to connect to another Virtual machine (**B**) with my tool there is a major issue. When you click once inside the RDP control where machine **B** is shown for the first time, the whole application gets stuck. The only way to unstuck it, is just click on the windows start key for example on machine **B** then back to the client tool and everything is OK, but this is rather unacceptable.

I found out that there are focus issues with the control, but the following **Failed** to resolve this (created new class which has the ax control as base class):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    //Fix for the missing focus issue on the rdp client component
    if (m.Msg == 0x0021)
    {
        this.Focus();
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

---

If anyone would be able to help with this, I would definitely appreciate it!

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
         {
             switch (m.Msg)
             {
                 case 0x021:
                     {
                         Message mm = new Message();
                         mm.Msg = 0x007;
                         base.WndProc(ref mm);
                     }
                     break;
             }
             base.WndProc(ref m);
         }
```

Comment: Thx! really worked very nicely, resolved a different bug also!
Would like to upvote, but I don't have enough reputation so it seems.